# How can I install a TV mount on a non flat stone wall?

Tags: walls, television, stone, mount

We moved to a new place that has a stone wall. There is a place to put the TV. In fact, I can see 5 holes in the wall.

[image]

I am wondering if I need to do anything special to install a TV wall mount. Reasons for asking:

- Wall is uneven and won’t flush.
- I want to reuse the existing holes, but they are only available on the upper side.

Comment: Those holes could be from something else. What is the flat material in the inset area?

Comment: What structure (if any) is behind the inset box and the flat material? Removing the inset box and the flat material, and then taking photos and editing the photos into your question would be helpful. You can edit your question to add photos using the "edit" button below the question text, followed by selecting the "moon and mountains" button that appears above the text entry area.

Comment: It looks like a decorative stone facade that's attached to the underlying wall, probably with some sort of adhesive or mortar. If you hang anything heavy from the stones themselves, I wouldn't trust that adhesive to hold. I can think of a few options - a lot depends on what sort of a wall sits behind the stones.

Comment: I'd start by removing the black plastic cable tray so to hopefully be able to see more of how the wall is constructed.

Comment: I am unaware of any TV mounts that use 5 holes in one horizontal line, does yours have that? Usually, there are 4 (or more) holes, each of which requires a bolt into a stud (or other sturdy material like plywood bolted to studs) and there are _two rows_ of bolts, one high, one low. I just can't imagine anything mounting securely into just those holes you've ID'd without _some_ other fastening. I wouldn't trust it to hold my TV. Heck, I've got 6 screws (3 into a joist and 3 into drywall anchors) to hold up a 14" square monitor on a ceiling mount.

Comment: I can’t tell for sure the inset material, but it feels like a wood hardboard. I am not sure how thick it is.

Comment: Could the previous mount be one of those no stud mounts? See https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/791113af-6948-4f7d-8374-1ae244e9b3b7/41459895.pdf and step 2C. @FreeMan

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how you fasten to the wall, one problem you need to solve is creating a flat plumb surface for the bracket.  Plastic standoffs will do that.  Most TV bracket kits come with a bunch of extra standoffs in different lengths, meant for TVs with non-flat backs so you could use those on your wall if they fit, maybe cutting them to suit each of the four stones you attach to or through.  If you can't use those you can get them at a hardware store.

Account for the standoffs in choosing the screw lengths once you determine what kind of screws you'll use.

Comment: By "screw" I presume you mean lag bolt into a stud behind? ;)

Comment: @FreeMan I mean screw in the most generic possible sense.    Fastener.  Since we don't know anything about the wall material I'm only addressing it's unevenness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. those are Stone Cladding, they will be glued to the back of the wall ( which i assume is some kind of drywall.

For peace of mind, i would just use two kinds of wall anchors. (expanding anchors, and spring toggle anchors)
[image]

The Wall Anchors expand at any postion (and hold really well) -- they will allow you to Fix the TV Mount (in the un-even brick) -- 3 or 4 plugs will be strong enough to hold a TV..

The Spring Toggles could go through the wall and can hold the Facade onto the wall.. (unless you can find a support beam, in which case you could just get a long screw.

Comment: I wouldn't count on an expanding anchor to hold much weight in that faux stone facade. It's probably 1/2 - 3/4" thick at the most, and most anchors need more depth than that to work. Even if they do anchor well in that, you're counting on the mastic behind them to hold. The spring toggles you've selected in your picture probably wouldn't have the strength to hold up a TV mount and any sort of sizeable TV, either. This simply needs lag screws through the stone and into the studs behind.

Comment: Agreed. if there are studs. it would be best drill directly into that. I guess we would need to know more about the actual curcumstances here...